# Is there an excel formula to remove the last full stop and the text following it from a string of text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of file names in excel such as: 
Brief Description of our Proposed Scheme.docx
and 
2018.05.30 DGOT Listing NS and MW.doc

I want a formula that will remove the full stop and the file type (eg. .doc or .docx) - as you can see the document type and full stop is either 4 or 5 characters in length from the end of the sentence

I have found other formulas but they either remove the text after the first full stop:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)))
```

or remove the text before the last full stop

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)))
```

Comment: Is it just docx or doc files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))))-1)
```

[image]

This is a typical formula to remove the filetype from a complete filespec.
Variations of this formula allow the extraction of the last word in a sentence, etc.